# Trying to call method in class from another method with JButton implementation

Tags: java, class, jbutton

I've been trying to implement JButton for an assignment in school, my first part of the code is working but it's looking really ugly, I get the feeling there has to be a better way than writing it like:

```
package labb2igen;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyButton extends JButton {
    public JFrame framen;
    Color col1;
    Color col2;
    String text1;
    String text2;
    JButton Button;

public MyButton(Color col1, Color col2, String text1, String text2) {
    this.col1=col1;
    this.col2=col2;
    this.text1=text1;
    this.text2=text2;
    Button=new JButton("Tryck här");
    Button.setBackground(col1);
    Button.setSize(300,300);
    framen=new JFrame("mybutton testing");
    framen.setSize(700,700);
    framen.setVisible(true);
    framen.add(Button);
}
public MyButton() {
    this.col1=Color.red;
    this.col2=Color.black;
    this.text1="hej";
    this.text2="nej";
    Button=new JButton("Tryck här");
    Button.setBackground(col1);
    Button.setSize(300,300);
    framen=new JFrame("mybutton testing");
    framen.setSize(700,700);
    framen.setVisible(true);
    framen.add(Button);

}
}
```

I realize that the code is probably looking bad from the start, but what really bothers me is that I have to implement the button and frame twice, I've been trying to switch from public MyButton(args) to public void MyButton(args) but then I cant run it in my Main method.

Comment: what do you mean, you implement the button and frame twice? and why do you "have to"? also: why do you have your Frame declared inside your Button? that makes no sense

Comment: I want the MyButton(); to call the MyButton(args); and get everything I've declared in there, but I can't make it work, is that not possible to achieve ?

Comment: why wouldn't that be possible? and why do you think that won't work?

Comment: I do believe its possible, I simply dont know how I'm supposed to do it, that's why I'm asking for help, if anyone knows a good way to let me get rid of some ugly code here...

Comment: try this(params)

Comment: thank you good sir! its been bothering me that it was looking so ugly, can I ask you, you asked why I declared my frame inside the button, do you have any advice for me concerning that?

Comment: yes, it makes no sense to declare a JFrame inside a Button. the button should be added to a JFrame, not the other way around

Comment: If you have time for one more quick question :D, I'm supposed to implement a togglestate method which toggles between states, as far as Im concerned im not supposed to use an actionlistener, is there a good way to do this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean: toggle between states? the state of your button? what state?

Comment: yes, the state of my button, im probably not using the right terms, but something to make it go from enabled to disabled or something, and as I change the states, I want to change colors, but Im not supposed to use an actionlistener

Comment: and what should trigger this? are you sure those methods aren't already there?

Comment: I dont think anything should trigger them besides me calling my method, I have a feeling that they may already be there, thanks a lot for your help sir!

Comment: setEnabled and such are already in JButton https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html